# How to Concat 2 columns in single column with column value check

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I want to concat two column from data frame where Column1 not equals to ANY:

DataFrame :

```
   COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
0     A    |   FOO
1     B    |   BAR  
2    ANY   |   FOO
3    ANY   |   BAR
4     C    |   FOO
```

as a result I want dataframe as follows

```
   COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
0     A    |  FOO_A
1     B    |  BAR_B
2    ANY   |  FOO
3    ANY   |  BAR  
4     C    |  FOO_C
```

ANY is variable, could represent Null, EmptyString, String, Number.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `Null` represent here? Is it a text string, is it `np.nan`?

Comment: It represents anything, like empty string, string, number, null. But I'm not using numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df['COLUMN2']=df.apply(lambda row:row['COLUMN2']+'_'+row['COLUMN1'] if row['COLUMN1']!='ANY' else row['COLUMN2'],axis=1)
```

Comment: good. Lambda is working here. as an advice use f concat for your strings. Like
```lambda row:f"{row['COLUMN2']}_{row['COLUMN1']}" if....```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
variable = "ANY"  #You could change this to any variable value
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if row["COLUMN1"] != variable:
        df.loc[idx,"COLUMN2"] = row["COLUMN2"] + "_" + row["COLUMN1"]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
```

```
  COLUMN1 COLUMN2
0       A   FOO_A
1       B   BAR_B
2     ANY     FOO
3     ANY     BAR
4       C   FOO_C
```

Comment: I dont want for loop. There should be single row solution.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop in this case is a bit faster than apply, since we are dealing with strings I guess.

```py
def concat_str(x,y):
    return x + "_" + y if y != 'ANY' else x

df['col2'] = [concat_str(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.col2.values, df.col1.values)]
```

Comment: wow no col3 please, actually question is derivatived from very huge datatable. So I dont prefer neither for loop nor extra column.

Comment: Just edited my answer. If your dataframe is large then it might worth doing this instead of apply

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a concern, you should be using `numpy` rather than `.apply` or any manually-written looping. In particular, `numpy.where()` should work for your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COLUMN1': ['A','B','ANY','ANY','C'],
    'COLUMN2': ['FOO','BAR','FOO','BAR','FOO']
})

df['COLUMN2'] = np.where(
    df['COLUMN1'].eq('ANY'),
    df['COLUMN2'],
    df['COLUMN1'] + '_' + df['COLUMN2']
)
```